# Wix 3.5 Icons on a push button control

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I am trying to create a "Help" button for my installer, bur for some reason my Icon does not appear on my push button.  Currently I am including the icon image in my main wix product wxs file as follows

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIInfoIcon" Value="Icons\info.ico"/>
```

Then in the wxs file I am using the icon I have the binary definition at the top as follows

```
<Binary Id="info" SourceFile="$(var.ICONS)\info.ico" />
```

ICONS is a variable I created with the file path that I QUADRUPLE checked to make sure it was accurate.  I am using this same technique with a bitmap elsewhere, and it appears so I have ruled out the variable as a known issue.

Then the button itself looks like this

```
    <Control Id="info" Type="PushButton" X="101" Y="51" Width="25" Height="23" ToolTip="Info for feature" Icon="yes" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="32"Text="info">
       <Publish Property="FEATURE_DESC_SHOW" Value="true"></Publish>
       <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="PopupDlgFeature">1</Publish>
    </Control>
```

Any ideas on something that I am doing wrong or something that is missing.  I feel a little foolish here that I can't figure this out, but sometimes the simplest of issue can cause the worst of problems am I right? lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was type conversion...when I converted my .bmp to a .ico something happened and the image was corrupted.  I went back and re-converted the image and now it works fine lol sorry for the any confusion I may have caused and please disregard my inadvertence in checking this earlier...